# Bootstrap container in a dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap dropdown menu, but I need to keep dropdown content max-width matching site width by using container. However, the solution that works is not a valid HTML. Please, check the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s5ug07t4/11/

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse js-navbar-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="dropdown mega-dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Main menu item</a>
      <!-- <div class="container">That's the issue causing container. It should be here, but the dropdown doesn't open then -->
      <ul class="dropdown-menu mega-dropdown-menu row">
      <div class="container"><!-- this is not valid HTML, but does the job right -->
        <li class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
          <ul>
```

Comment: Can you be more clear? When I remove the issue-causing `container` div, it looks exactly the same and it still is full width. So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: The issue-causing container is commented in the fiddle so you can see how it should work. However, when you uncomment it and comment the invalid `container` div, dropdown won't open: https://jsfiddle.net/s5ug07t4/17/